# asp.net core 2.2 post request is not reaching an endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, http-status-code-400

All the get requests work fine locally and on the server. posts work fine locally but return 400 (bad request) when I upload the project to the server.

For testing purposes I tried to isolate the problem by removing auth and anti-forgery fillers on the controller in question.

```
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
     [ApiController]
     [AllowAnonymous]
     [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
```

I also removed the CorsPolicypolicy filter globally using:

```
   services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

and here's my configure method:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/error");
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: Have you putted `[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]` in the controller? I had a similar issue and this fixed it.

Comment: I added CorsPolicy on the controller but it's the same 
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]

Comment: What is the server you are hosting to? The issue might not be a code related one.

Comment: I am using a digital ocean and docker container. other requests work except post though. @antonios-katopodis

Comment: Can you try to debug using postman? Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: @YanivAmrami you are right, I am handling http -> https redirection on Nginx side not from API (using  app.UseHttpsRedirection();) so after 301 redirection post body is lost I guess. I am looking at that. Thanks for the quality comment.